# Xamarin.Forms ChangeCanExecute not using the right parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, freshmvvm

I have a Xamarin.Forms application running in UWP where I use the DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView (from [daniel-luberda](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView)) to display some kind of grid view with buttons.

The Mvvm framework used is FreshMvvm.

Here is my gridview in XAML:

```
<c:FlowListView SeparatorVisibility="None" 
    HasUnevenRows="False" FlowColumnMinWidth="100" 
    FlowItemsSource="{Binding Boards}">
    <c:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button  Text="{Binding Number}" 
                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.SelectBoardCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=SalesPage}}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </c:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</c:FlowListView>
```

Here is the result (I simplified the XAML concerning color and size) :

[image: Gridview]

The button inside my gridview is binded to a command with a parameter.  Each time I click on a button, I would like to disable it.

And my command looks like this:

```
    private ICommand _selectBoardCommand;

    [DoNotNotify]
    public ICommand SelectBoardCommand => _selectBoardCommand = new Command<BoardModel>(board =>
    {
        board.NotUsed = false;
        ((Command<BoardModel>) _selectBoardCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
    }, board => board != null && board.NotUsed);
```

Pushing on a button calls the command with the right parameter (the board.Number binded to the text of the command is the one I get in the command).
But when calling the "CanChangeExecute" in order to disable the command, I can't pass the selected board as argument.

And in the command, when using

```
((Command<BoardModel>) _selectBoardCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
```

it calls the Func

```
board => board != null && board.NotUsed
```

with the latest item of the list.

Moreover, I needed to put a "board != null" in the ChangeCanExecute because this Func is called a lot of time with null values.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure its not an issue with the FlowListView?

Comment: @Andy Just tested and same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways out of your problem:
1) Move `SelectBoardCommand` inside `BoardModel`. It won't need a parameter and will operate on each model individually;
2) Bind `Enabled` property of `Button` to `NotUsed` property. In this case, user won't be able to call `SelectBoardCommand` from UI at all.

Comment: I cannot put the command inside BoardModel as there is much more code in the command that is tightly coupled with my ViewModel.

Comment: And I already tried the binding to the Enabled property of the button but as soon as you bind your button with a Command, the Enabled is not used anymore.

Comment: If we keep in mind, that technically we work with `ListView` and `ItemTappedCommand`, the command should never have `CanExecute` returning `false`. The cell can always be tapped but inside the `command` implementation we put `if (board?.NotUsed) { ... }`

Comment: That's a good workaround even if visually, the button is always enabled.

Comment: I accept your answer thanks to your comment "if (board?.NotUser)" ... thanks a lot